# Multiple DbContexts single Interface?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have **n** environments each managed by a DbContext (and EntityFramework). They are all the "same" database (but differences may occur) and the requirement is to provide a means to copy between environments.

I'm currently going about this in the below way.

```
public class TableA
    {
        public string FieldA { get; set; }
        public string FieldB { get; set; }
        public string FieldC { get; set; }

        public static void Copy(EnvironmentTypes to, EnvironmentTypes from, int id)
        {
            var fromModel = TableA.Get(from,id);

            TableA.Add(to,fromModel);
        }

        public static TableA Get(EnvironmentTypes env, int id)
        {
            switch (env)
            {
                case EnvironmentTypes.Development
                    using (var db = new DevelopmentContext.DevelopmentEntities())
                    {
                        var entity = db.TableA.Find(id);

                        return Mapper.Map<TableA>(entity); // using AutoMapper
                    }
                    break;
                case EnvironmentTypes.SystemTest
                    using (var db = new SystemTestContext.SystemTestEntities())
                    {
                        var entity = db.TableA.Find(id);

                        return Mapper.Map<TableA>(entity); // using AutoMapper
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static TableA Add(EnvironmentTypes env, TableA fromModel)
        {
            switch (env)
            {
                case EnvironmentTypes.Development
                    using (var db = new DevelopmentContext.DevelopmentEntities())
                    {
                        db.TableA.Add(Mapper.Map<DevelopmentContext.TableA>(fromModel));
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return fromModel; 
                    }
                    break;
                case EnvironmentTypes.SystemTest
                    using (var db = new SystemTestContext.SystemTestEntities())
                    {
                        db.TableA.Add(Mapper.Map<SystemTestContext.TableA>(fromModel));
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return fromModel; 
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is leading to lots of 1. code replication, 2. object replication (i've already got n times the number of entities in their POCO classes, and now I'm needing to replicate the class again).

There maybe differences in the environments, hence the use of Automapper.

How can I get rid of this duplication of code and make the flow cleaner?

Comment: Personally, I'd use one data-context type, with different connections/connection-strings, and worry about the data as part of a TSQL migration script.

Comment: Looks like this is the way I'm going to have to go. I was clearly attempting to make it far more complicated than needed!